# jquery dynamic dependent select from multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multidimensional-array

I am trying to have to have a form with two drop down select options that are populated from arrays. The first select has only one array, however depending on the selection, I want to populate the second with a specific multidimensional array. I am able to do them individually, but I am unable to pass the array name from the first selection to the function to populate the second.

I am pretty new to javascript and jQuery 1.11.0 and would appreciate any assistance.

Here is the code I am working with.

```
select name="aircraftList" id="aircraftList" onchange="showAircraft(this.selectedIndex)"

select name="configWBList" id="configWBList"

// values for AIRCRAFT
// tnumber, acmodel, maxwt, f1arm, m1arm, r1arm, littarm, bag1max, fuel1kgmax, 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
var aircraft = [
    ["Select Aircraft", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ['N901AH', "Agusta A109E", 3000, 1585, 2455, 3200, 5300, 3200, 150, 480],
    ['N902AH', "Agusta A109E", 3000, 1585, 2455, 3200, 5300, 3200, 150, 480],
    ['N903AH', "Agusta A109E", 3000, 1585, 2455, 3200, 5300, 3200, 150, 480],
    ['N904AH', "Agusta A109E", 3000, 1585, 2455, 3200, 5300, 3200, 150, 480],
    ['N905AH', "Agusta A109E", 3000, 1585, 2455, 3200, 5300, 3200, 150, 480],
    ['N907AH', "Agusta A109E", 3000, 1585, 2455, 3200, 5300, 3200, 150, 480]
];

// values for AC N901AH
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
var N901AH = [
    ["Select a Configuration", "Select Config", "Select Config"],
    ["6 PAX STANDARD SEATS OFFSHORE", 2205.61, 3485.69],
    ["DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2207.81, 3483.76],
    ["VIP SEATS INSTALLED", 2212.11, 3483.75],
    ["VIP SEATS, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2214.31, 3481.83],
    ["ONE LITTER KIT INSTALLED", 2213.91, 3483.50],
    ["ONE LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2216.11, 3481.58],
    ["6 PAX STANDARD SEATS, VESTS REMOVED", 2196.81, 3489.83],
    ["VIP SEATS INSTALLED, VEST REMOVED", 2203.31, 3487.87],
    ["ONE LITTER INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2207.31, 3487.02],
    ["TWO LITTER INSTALLED", 2222.21, 3481.32],
    ["TWO LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2224.41, 3479.41],
    ["VIP SEATS, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2205.51, 3485.93],
    ["ONE LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2209.51, 3485.09],
    ["TWO LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2220.01, 3482.33],
    ["FLOATS, RAFT, VESTS REMOVED", 2084.51, 3507.26]
];

// values for AC N902AH
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
var N902AH = [
    ["Select a Configuration", "Select Config", "Select Config"],
    ["6 PAX STANDARD SEATS OFFSHORE", 2205.61, 3485.69],
    ["DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2207.81, 3483.76],
    ["VIP SEATS INSTALLED", 2212.11, 3483.75],
    ["VIP SEATS, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2214.31, 3481.83],
    ["ONE LITTER KIT INSTALLED", 2213.91, 3483.50],
    ["ONE LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2216.11, 3481.58],
    ["6 PAX STANDARD SEATS, VESTS REMOVED", 2196.81, 3489.83],
    ["VIP SEATS INSTALLED, VEST REMOVED", 2203.31, 3487.87],
    ["ONE LITTER INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2207.31, 3487.02],
    ["TWO LITTER INSTALLED", 2222.21, 3481.32],
    ["TWO LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2224.41, 3479.41],
    ["VIP SEATS, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2205.51, 3485.93],
    ["ONE LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2209.51, 3485.09],
    ["TWO LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2220.01, 3482.33],
    ["FLOATS, RAFT, VESTS REMOVED", 2084.51, 3507.26]
];

// values for AC N903AH
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
var N903AH = [
    ["Select a Configuration", "Select Config", "Select Config"],
    ["6 PAX STANDARD SEATS OFFSHORE", 2205.61, 3485.69],
    ["DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2207.81, 3483.76],
    ["VIP SEATS INSTALLED", 2212.11, 3483.75],
    ["VIP SEATS, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2214.31, 3481.83],
    ["ONE LITTER KIT INSTALLED", 2213.91, 3483.50],
    ["ONE LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2216.11, 3481.58],
    ["6 PAX STANDARD SEATS, VESTS REMOVED", 2196.81, 3489.83],
    ["VIP SEATS INSTALLED, VEST REMOVED", 2203.31, 3487.87],
    ["ONE LITTER INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2207.31, 3487.02],
    ["TWO LITTER INSTALLED", 2222.21, 3481.32],
    ["TWO LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2224.41, 3479.41],
    ["VIP SEATS, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2205.51, 3485.93],
    ["ONE LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2209.51, 3485.09],
    ["TWO LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2220.01, 3482.33],
    ["FLOATS, RAFT, VESTS REMOVED", 2084.51, 3507.26]
];

// values for AC N904AH
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
var N904AH = [
    ["Select a Configuration", "Select Config", "Select Config"],
    ["6 PAX STANDARD SEATS OFFSHORE", 2205.61, 3485.69],
    ["DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2207.81, 3483.76],
    ["VIP SEATS INSTALLED", 2212.11, 3483.75],
    ["VIP SEATS, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2214.31, 3481.83],
    ["ONE LITTER KIT INSTALLED", 2213.91, 3483.50],
    ["ONE LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2216.11, 3481.58],
    ["6 PAX STANDARD SEATS, VESTS REMOVED", 2196.81, 3489.83],
    ["VIP SEATS INSTALLED, VEST REMOVED", 2203.31, 3487.87],
    ["ONE LITTER INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2207.31, 3487.02],
    ["TWO LITTER INSTALLED", 2222.21, 3481.32],
    ["TWO LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2224.41, 3479.41],
    ["VIP SEATS, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2205.51, 3485.93],
    ["ONE LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2209.51, 3485.09],
    ["TWO LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2220.01, 3482.33],
    ["FLOATS, RAFT, VESTS REMOVED", 2084.51, 3507.26]
];

// values for AC N905AH
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
var N905AH = [
    ["Select a Configuration", "Select Config", "Select Config"],
    ["6 PAX STANDARD SEATS OFFSHORE", 2205.61, 3485.69],
    ["DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2207.81, 3483.76],
    ["VIP SEATS INSTALLED", 2212.11, 3483.75],
    ["VIP SEATS, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2214.31, 3481.83],
    ["ONE LITTER KIT INSTALLED", 2213.91, 3483.50],
    ["ONE LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2216.11, 3481.58],
    ["6 PAX STANDARD SEATS, VESTS REMOVED", 2196.81, 3489.83],
    ["VIP SEATS INSTALLED, VEST REMOVED", 2203.31, 3487.87],
    ["ONE LITTER INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2207.31, 3487.02],
    ["TWO LITTER INSTALLED", 2222.21, 3481.32],
    ["TWO LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2224.41, 3479.41],
    ["VIP SEATS, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2205.51, 3485.93],
    ["ONE LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2209.51, 3485.09],
    ["TWO LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2220.01, 3482.33],
    ["FLOATS, RAFT, VESTS REMOVED", 2084.51, 3507.26]
];

// values for AC N907AH
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
var N907AH = [
    ["Select a Configuration", "Select Config", "Select Config"],
    ["6 PAX STANDARD SEATS OFFSHORE", 2205.61, 3485.69],
    ["DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2207.81, 3483.76],
    ["VIP SEATS INSTALLED", 2212.11, 3483.75],
    ["VIP SEATS, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2214.31, 3481.83],
    ["ONE LITTER KIT INSTALLED", 2213.91, 3483.50],
    ["ONE LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2216.11, 3481.58],
    ["6 PAX STANDARD SEATS, VESTS REMOVED", 2196.81, 3489.83],
    ["VIP SEATS INSTALLED, VEST REMOVED", 2203.31, 3487.87],
    ["ONE LITTER INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2207.31, 3487.02],
    ["TWO LITTER INSTALLED", 2222.21, 3481.32],
    ["TWO LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2224.41, 3479.41],
    ["VIP SEATS, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2205.51, 3485.93],
    ["ONE LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2209.51, 3485.09],
    ["TWO LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2220.01, 3482.33],
    ["FLOATS, RAFT, VESTS REMOVED", 2084.51, 3507.26]
];


// set form values to selected aircraft option  
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function showAircraft(idx) {
    var aircraftWB = [aircraft[idx][0]]
    alert(aircraftWB);
    $("#configWBList").html('');
    list(aircraftWB);
}

function list(arrary) {
    alert(arrary);

    // populate selected aircraft w&b select
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    for (i = 0; i < arrary.length; i++) {
        var select = document.getElementById("configWBList");
        select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(arrary[i][0], arrary[i][1]);
    }

    // reset the selected aircraft configuration to standard
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $("#configWBList").val($("#configWBList option:first").val());
    $("#configWBList").selectmenu('refresh', true);

}


// initialise form
// ****************************************************
function initForm() {
    // populate aircraft select
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    for (i = 0; i < aircraft.length; i++) {
        var select = document.getElementById("aircraftList");
        select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(aircraft[i][0], aircraft[i][1]);
    }
}

initForm();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g3h9p2ur/

Comment: Are you stuck with the information in that form or are you writing those arrays yourself? If you can modify them, associative arrays might be a better choice.

Comment: No, I am writing those arrays myself.  As I said I am very new to jQuery (my first project) and I could not get associative arrays to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "eval" to get the result variable data.

```html
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
var aircraft = [
    ["Select Aircraft", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ['N901AH', "Agusta A109E", 3000, 1585, 2455, 3200, 5300, 3200, 150, 480],
    ['N902AH', "Agusta A109E", 3000, 1585, 2455, 3200, 5300, 3200, 150, 480],
    ['N903AH', "Agusta A109E", 3000, 1585, 2455, 3200, 5300, 3200, 150, 480],
    ['N904AH', "Agusta A109E", 3000, 1585, 2455, 3200, 5300, 3200, 150, 480],
    ['N905AH', "Agusta A109E", 3000, 1585, 2455, 3200, 5300, 3200, 150, 480],
    ['N907AH', "Agusta A109E", 3000, 1585, 2455, 3200, 5300, 3200, 150, 480]
];

// values for AC N901AH
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
var N901AH = [
    ["Select a Configuration1", "Select Config", "Select Config"],
    ["6 PAX STANDARD SEATS OFFSHORE", 2205.61, 3485.69],
    ["DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2207.81, 3483.76],
    ["VIP SEATS INSTALLED", 2212.11, 3483.75],
    ["VIP SEATS, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2214.31, 3481.83],
    ["ONE LITTER KIT INSTALLED", 2213.91, 3483.50],
    ["ONE LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2216.11, 3481.58],
    ["6 PAX STANDARD SEATS, VESTS REMOVED", 2196.81, 3489.83],
    ["VIP SEATS INSTALLED, VEST REMOVED", 2203.31, 3487.87],
    ["ONE LITTER INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2207.31, 3487.02],
    ["TWO LITTER INSTALLED", 2222.21, 3481.32],
    ["TWO LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2224.41, 3479.41],
    ["VIP SEATS, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2205.51, 3485.93],
    ["ONE LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2209.51, 3485.09],
    ["TWO LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2220.01, 3482.33],
    ["FLOATS, RAFT, VESTS REMOVED", 2084.51, 3507.26]
];

// values for AC N902AH
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
var N902AH = [
    ["Select a Configuration2", "Select Config", "Select Config"],
    ["6 PAX STANDARD SEATS OFFSHORE", 2205.61, 3485.69],
    ["DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2207.81, 3483.76],
    ["VIP SEATS INSTALLED", 2212.11, 3483.75],
    ["VIP SEATS, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2214.31, 3481.83],
    ["ONE LITTER KIT INSTALLED", 2213.91, 3483.50],
    ["ONE LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2216.11, 3481.58],
    ["6 PAX STANDARD SEATS, VESTS REMOVED", 2196.81, 3489.83],
    ["VIP SEATS INSTALLED, VEST REMOVED", 2203.31, 3487.87],
    ["ONE LITTER INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2207.31, 3487.02],
    ["TWO LITTER INSTALLED", 2222.21, 3481.32],
    ["TWO LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2224.41, 3479.41],
    ["VIP SEATS, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2205.51, 3485.93],
    ["ONE LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2209.51, 3485.09],
    ["TWO LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2220.01, 3482.33],
    ["FLOATS, RAFT, VESTS REMOVED", 2084.51, 3507.26]
];

// values for AC N903AH
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
var N903AH = [
    ["Select a Configuration3", "Select Config", "Select Config"],
    ["6 PAX STANDARD SEATS OFFSHORE", 2205.61, 3485.69],
    ["DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2207.81, 3483.76],
    ["VIP SEATS INSTALLED", 2212.11, 3483.75],
    ["VIP SEATS, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2214.31, 3481.83],
    ["ONE LITTER KIT INSTALLED", 2213.91, 3483.50],
    ["ONE LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2216.11, 3481.58],
    ["6 PAX STANDARD SEATS, VESTS REMOVED", 2196.81, 3489.83],
    ["VIP SEATS INSTALLED, VEST REMOVED", 2203.31, 3487.87],
    ["ONE LITTER INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2207.31, 3487.02],
    ["TWO LITTER INSTALLED", 2222.21, 3481.32],
    ["TWO LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2224.41, 3479.41],
    ["VIP SEATS, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2205.51, 3485.93],
    ["ONE LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2209.51, 3485.09],
    ["TWO LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2220.01, 3482.33],
    ["FLOATS, RAFT, VESTS REMOVED", 2084.51, 3507.26]
];

// values for AC N904AH
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
var N904AH = [
    ["Select a Configuration", "Select Config", "Select Config"],
    ["6 PAX STANDARD SEATS OFFSHORE", 2205.61, 3485.69],
    ["DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2207.81, 3483.76],
    ["VIP SEATS INSTALLED", 2212.11, 3483.75],
    ["VIP SEATS, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2214.31, 3481.83],
    ["ONE LITTER KIT INSTALLED", 2213.91, 3483.50],
    ["ONE LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2216.11, 3481.58],
    ["6 PAX STANDARD SEATS, VESTS REMOVED", 2196.81, 3489.83],
    ["VIP SEATS INSTALLED, VEST REMOVED", 2203.31, 3487.87],
    ["ONE LITTER INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2207.31, 3487.02],
    ["TWO LITTER INSTALLED", 2222.21, 3481.32],
    ["TWO LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2224.41, 3479.41],
    ["VIP SEATS, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2205.51, 3485.93],
    ["ONE LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2209.51, 3485.09],
    ["TWO LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2220.01, 3482.33],
    ["FLOATS, RAFT, VESTS REMOVED", 2084.51, 3507.26]
];

// values for AC N905AH
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
var N905AH = [
    ["Select a Configuration", "Select Config", "Select Config"],
    ["6 PAX STANDARD SEATS OFFSHORE", 2205.61, 3485.69],
    ["DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2207.81, 3483.76],
    ["VIP SEATS INSTALLED", 2212.11, 3483.75],
    ["VIP SEATS, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2214.31, 3481.83],
    ["ONE LITTER KIT INSTALLED", 2213.91, 3483.50],
    ["ONE LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2216.11, 3481.58],
    ["6 PAX STANDARD SEATS, VESTS REMOVED", 2196.81, 3489.83],
    ["VIP SEATS INSTALLED, VEST REMOVED", 2203.31, 3487.87],
    ["ONE LITTER INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2207.31, 3487.02],
    ["TWO LITTER INSTALLED", 2222.21, 3481.32],
    ["TWO LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2224.41, 3479.41],
    ["VIP SEATS, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2205.51, 3485.93],
    ["ONE LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2209.51, 3485.09],
    ["TWO LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2220.01, 3482.33],
    ["FLOATS, RAFT, VESTS REMOVED", 2084.51, 3507.26]
];

// values for AC N907AH
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
var N907AH = [
    ["Select a Configuration", "Select Config", "Select Config"],
    ["6 PAX STANDARD SEATS OFFSHORE", 2205.61, 3485.69],
    ["DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2207.81, 3483.76],
    ["VIP SEATS INSTALLED", 2212.11, 3483.75],
    ["VIP SEATS, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2214.31, 3481.83],
    ["ONE LITTER KIT INSTALLED", 2213.91, 3483.50],
    ["ONE LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2216.11, 3481.58],
    ["6 PAX STANDARD SEATS, VESTS REMOVED", 2196.81, 3489.83],
    ["VIP SEATS INSTALLED, VEST REMOVED", 2203.31, 3487.87],
    ["ONE LITTER INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2207.31, 3487.02],
    ["TWO LITTER INSTALLED", 2222.21, 3481.32],
    ["TWO LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED", 2224.41, 3479.41],
    ["VIP SEATS, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2205.51, 3485.93],
    ["ONE LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2209.51, 3485.09],
    ["TWO LITTER, DUAL CONTROLS INSTALLED, VESTS REMOVED", 2220.01, 3482.33],
    ["FLOATS, RAFT, VESTS REMOVED", 2084.51, 3507.26]
];
//alert(eval('N901AH'));
var subListValue="";
$( document ).ready(function() {
//alert(aircraft.length);

   for(i=0;i<aircraft.length;i++)
   {
 
  $('#list1')
         .append($("<option></option>")
         .attr("value",aircraft[i][0])
         .text(aircraft[i][0]));
   
  
   }
   
   
   $('#list1').on('change', function() {
   $('#list2').empty();
  subListValue=eval(this.value ); // or $(this).val()
  for(i=0;i<subListValue.length;i++)
   {
 
  $('#list2')
         .append($("<option></option>")
         .attr("value",subListValue[i][0])
         .text(subListValue[i][0]));
   
  
   }
});
});
</script>
<select id="list1">
</select>
<select id="list2">
</select>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

What I would suggest is to create an object from the arrays like:

```
var aircrafts = { "N901AH" : N901AH, "N902AH" : N902AH, "N903AH" : N903AH, "N904AH" : N904AH, "N905AH" : N905AH, "N907AH" : N907AH};
```

Also instead of for loop use $.each(array, handler(index, element)). Then instead of eval() use the option text to get the array you need from the object:

```
console.log(aircrafts["N901AH"]);//example
```

and populate the second select. 
Here is my fiddle on this:
[jsfiddle for my answer](http://jsfiddle.net/mzografski/p1dn5vfe/)

Regards.

Comment: is there a reason not to the the eval()?

Comment: it converts string into executable JavaScript. it is a possible breaking point for attack. More in the link:
http://jslinterrors.com/eval-is-evil